# conditional expectation as direct sum

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, projection

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability measure space and $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{G})$ =$\{$X $\mathcal{G}$-measurebale , $\int XdP<\infty$ $\}$  for  $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ an abritrary sub $\sigma$-Algebra.

$\circ$ Is $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{G})$ modulo Nullsets with $|| \cdot ||_1$ a closed subset of $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{F})$  / a Banach space?

$\circ$ Is there some other Subspace $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{G}) \oplus \mathcal{S}  =\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{F})$ or even a $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{G}) \oplus  \mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{H}) =\mathcal{L}^1(\mathcal{F})$?

Comment: For the first bullet, note that convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence a.s. along a subsequence, and that any a.s. limit of $\cal G$-measurable functions is $\cal G$-measurable.

Comment: For the second bullet, let $\mathcal S :=\{Y:E[Y|\mathcal G]=0\}$, and noting that $X=E[X|\mathcal G]+(X-E[X|\mathcal G])$.

Comment: Finally, note it is impossible that $\mathcal S = L^1(\mathcal H)$, because $1 \in L^1(\mathcal G) \cap L^1(\mathcal H)$, for any $\cal G,H$.